# Devo referenciar minhas pesquisas no Wiki?

Tags: suporte, proposta-para-faq, wikis-de-tags

Aproveitei meu tempo livre para escrever o wiki de algumas tags de pesquisa. Em algumas delas eu precisei gastar um tempinho pesquisando, para deixá-las mais completas.

Devo referenciar todos os meios que utilizei para pesquisar e formular o wiki ou o texto deve ser objetivo e sem links externos?

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de incluir a tag [meta-tag:proposta-para-faq], acho que esse conteúdo seria importante no nosso FAQ.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Referenciar *tudo que você leu* durante a pesquisa não precisa.

#### É desejável referenciar:

- as fontes que mais te influenciaram na elaboração do conteúdo;
- as fontes que possam dar informações adicionais úteis a quem estiver lendo.

#### É obrigatório referenciar:

- qualquer fonte que você tenha transcrito total ou parcialmente no wiki.

#### É dispensável referenciar:

- material simplesmente redundante;
- fontes com informações incompletas e/ou que não foram fundamentais na pesquisa;
- fontes com informações incorretas – exceto quando identificadas como tais e com valor para o entendimento do correto.