# "Eu acho que você merece ser [faq], sua pergunta linda"

Tags: suporte, meta

O que fazer se eu encontrar uma pergunta selvagem e crer que ela deve virar [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)? E quando você percebe que talvez sua própria pergunta, meses depois de nascer, merece ser [faq](/questions/tagged/faq)?

Editar ela para por a meta-tag [proposta-para-faq](/questions/tagged/proposta-para-faq) em perguntas de terceiros parece ser intrusivo.

Exemplos de perguntas que eu falei "Eu acho que você merece ser [faq], sua pergunta linda":

- [Oh, não! Editaram minha pergunta!](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2212/64969)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É irônico que o exemplo citado praticamente responde esta pergunta :)

[Siga as instruções e seja feliz](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/699/101). Se acha que a pergunta merece estar na FAQ, edite, demonstre que acha isto, só assim o processo anda, não importa quem fez a pergunta, o importante é contribuir para a comunidade funcionar melhor.

Comment: Ok, me senti um preguiçoso agora xP... #vergonhaDefine

Comment: Encontrei aqui um comentário sobre o tema: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2368/devo-referenciar-minhas-pesquisas-no-wiki#comment7969_2368; parafraseando: "tomei a liberdade de incluir a tag [meta-tag:proposta-para-faq]"